# Laravel Datatable displayed in JSON format

Tags: php, laravel, mv, yajra-datatable

i have to show the data in a form of datatable i use YajraBox Laravel Datatable  to do that but it displayed in JSON format

```
/*Route code*/
Route::get('/editing','TlController@modif')->name('modif'); 

/*the Controller code*/
    public function modif(){


      return DataTables::of(Weekends::query())->make(true);
    } 
/*View code*/
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('containers')
<table class="table table-bordered" id="weekends-table">
    <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>idm</th>
            <th>fday</th>
            <th>sday</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>updated_at</th>
            <th>created_at</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#weekends-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('modif') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'idm', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'fday', name: 'first day of weekend' },
            { data: 'sday', name: 'second day of weekend' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
@endsection
```

this is how it represents the data:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTWwK.png

Comment: You're missing a `<tbody>` tag, which is required for DataTables.

Comment: how ? because i did as in the documentation but i don't get the result

Comment: It's supposed to be returning JSON, since that's what the plugin expects. I don't use the default get request from the `ajax` property, but I think you might need to double check that the route is compatible with it.

Comment: have you install snappy pdf? because information from this tutorial https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-datatables-export-to-pdf-file-exampleexample.html we should install snappy

Answer (score 0):

As first commentor said, try to add this after `<thead>` if it will work, also don't forget the closing `</table>` tag:

```html
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="6">No data.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: there are not , it's displaying json instead of my view

Answer (score 0):

```
        <tr>
            <th>idm</th>
            <th>fday</th>
            <th>sday</th>
            <th>updated_at</th>
            <th>created_at</th>
        </tr>
```

There are 5 parameters in your js and you have 6 parameters in .
You should have exact amount of parameters passed in your js and inside  tag of your table. :)

Comment: it's giving the same result , JSON DATA